# An injective map into a subset of an infinite set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can we have an injective map from $X$ to $X-A$ where $A$ is a subset of $X$? The answer is clearly no when $X$ is a finite set but I wonder if this is possible when $X$ is a set with infinite number of elements.

Comment: an example is the map from naturals to even numbers $f :N\rightarrow A$ as $f(n)=2*n$

Comment: Thank you !! Is it appropriate to say in this context that we can consider natural numbers as a subset of even natural numbers ?

Comment: no it just means that the cardinality of naturals is less than or equal to cardinality of even numbers.As u can clearly see 1 is a natural number but not in even numbers

Comment: Your comment "The answer is clearly no when $X$ is a finite set" is actually quite insightful.  One standard *definition* of  finiteness is to say that $X$ is finite precisely when there is no injection from $X$ to any proper subset $B\subsetneq X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an example is the map from naturals to even numbers $f:N \rightarrow A$ as $f(n)=2∗n$. Infact If $X$ is infinite and $A$ is finite subset then there is a bijection from $X-A\rightarrow X$.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on X and your choice of A. Suppose that X is the reals and A is the irrationals, then X\A is the rationals and you can't inject the reals into the rationals. On the other hand if X is the natural numbers and A is the even (or odd) natural numbers then yes.

Stating the obvious, you can't inject X into X\A if |X\A| < |X|.

Comment: I reckon the last part of what you said is pretty circular as this is how we define the cardinalities of sets (as in to check that $|X\A|<|X|$ we would need to prove there is no injection)

Comment: @hmmmm The OP seems to be looking for some answer to whether there is an injection from X to X\A. The answer is yes in some circumstances and no in others. After the two examples I'm just giving the general rule i.e. no if |X\A| < |X| and yes otherwise.

Comment: Yes I wasn't saying there was anything wrong with that it's just that $|X \ A|< |X|$ is defined to mean that there is not an injection from $|X|$ to $|X \ A|$. Hence in order to show that $|X\A|<|X|$ you would need to show that there is no injection, so to show there is no injection you need to show there is no injection. Unless of course you know a priori the size of the sets. It was a trivial point though, I should not have mentioned it

Comment: I'm interested in this example: Can we find an injective map from $[0,1)$ to $[\dfrac{1}{2},1)$?

Comment: @palio Yes. x -> 1/2 + x/2

Comment: @hmmmm. It's Ok. Your last observation is quite pertinent as I did construct the examples by knowing the size of the sets (which someone else probably established by looking at injections !).